# generating a file using ifstream to create a username and password file

Tags: c++

so im trying to create a program to where it asks the user for a username and password whenever you go to register or log in. The code runs with no errors, except for whenever i go to log in it automatically logs me in without letting me type the username or password to actually log in. this is the code i have so car

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

bool IsLoggedIn()
{
    string username, password, un, pw;

    cout << "PLease enter your username!" << endl;
    cin >> username;
    cout << "Please enter your password!" << endl;
    cin >> password;

    ifstream read("data\\" + username + ".txt");

    getline(read, un);
    getline(read, pw);

    if (un == username && pw == password)
    {
        return true;
    }

    else
    {
        return false;
    }


}




int main()
{

    int choice;

    cout << "Press 1 to register\n Press 2 to Login" << endl;
    cin >> choice;

    if (choice == 1)
    {
        string username, password;

        cout << "select a username:" << endl;
        cin >> username;
        cout << "select a password:" << endl;
        cin >> password;


        ofstream file;
        file.open("data\\" + username + ".txt");
        file << username << endl << password;
        file.close();

        main();


    }
    else if (choice == 2)
    {
        bool status = IsLoggedIn;

        if (!status)
        {

            cout << "incorrect login" << endl;
            system("pause");
            return 0;


        }
        else
        {
            cout << "successfully logged in!" << endl;
            system("pause");
            return 1;
        }


    }







}
```

Comment: Please show how do you call this `IsLoggedIn()` function

Comment: `bool status = IsLoggedIn;` that's not how to call the function `IsLoggedIn()`.  That's simply checking if a function's address is non-zero.  Which is always `true`.

Comment: Side note: Never call `main` in a program. Only the runtime system should ever call it. You have no idea what weird implementation smurf could be lurking out of your sight. Plus you never want to allow a user to control the exit condition of a recursive function. They will screw it up.

Comment: Jack up the compiler warnings and it'll tell you a lot: https://godbolt.org/z/Yxafh97jh Here I've turned on what I consider the absolute minimum for GCC and clang and turned on a couple sanitizers to make it easier to trap and diagnose runtime errors.

Comment: I can not stress enough - you want your compiler warnings turned on.  It will solve problems _much faster_ than asking strangers to compile your code with their warnings turned on.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
    bool status = IsLoggedIn;
```

*(which assigns a function's address to a `bool`)*

to:

```
    bool status = IsLoggedIn();
```

*(which calls the function and assigns the return value to a `bool`)*

Your code currently never calls the function `IsLoggedIn()`;